# Programmatically grab display icons

Tags: objective-c, macos

[image: Display Icon]

I noticed in OSX that in the display settings there are unique icons for different displays.  For example my laptop will show something like the picture above, but an external monitor will look different.

Is there any way to programmatically get these icons such that if I give an display ID.  I will received the same icon that would have shown up in the settings window?  My guess is that I can only find the resource files for these images and make my own decision.  But figured I would ask and see!